# Single Method Class Approaches

Tags: scala

I see the following code for a single method class written by a colleague:

```
class Foo(boo: Boo){
  def doSomething() {...}
}
```

where there are data initialization with application configuration data. I am wondering what is its advantages over the following approach.

```
object Foo {
  def doSomething(boo: Boo){...}
}
```

The approach, I think, is better for a situation which an instead of the class is created in a place and the method is invoked in another place where there isn't access to the parameters. For what I see, it isn't used in the situation described above. What else in terms of comparison of those two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is better in terms of memory and performance, since it doesn't require an object instantiation every time you simply want to call that method.

The first approach, however, might be more maintainable if you want to add new parameters. If the computations done within the method need some form of caching for that specific instance of `Foo`, you can also trivially add new fields.

In general, in depends on the broader context which way should be preferred. For configuration data or other context holders, the second approach might make more sense, since these shouldn't be referenced by some random instances anyway.

Comment: Thanks both for your inputs. I never write my code in the fashion. The code let me wondering whether I miss something in the past or not. think that another advantage of this first approach in a situation where a constructor takes a long time to complete. In a such case, the constructor can invoked during the application startup.

Comment: I think it's largely a hangover from the way Java development tends to be done. With Spring/Guice it would be simple to get the framework to manage the configuration and injection of Foo for you if you used the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's primarily a matter of taste. I agree with you that probably using an `object` is better here, also because it avoids unnecessary allocation of class `Foo`. On the other hand, a value class would also be "allocation free" and behind the scenes do something similar to the singleton object:

```
trait Boo

class Foo(val boo: Boo) extends AnyVal {
  def doSomething() = ???
}
```